# Extract text from popup / by mouse hovering on web element with selenium

Tags: java, selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOQtp.png)I need to find a way how I could get the text from the popup using selenium/ java so that I can compare the text with expected data.

Is there anyway I could extract the text from the popup. Screenshot attached. Thanks in advance.

I tried following but no luck

```
WebElement lMail=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='ACE'][@class='footer-title twc-blue twc-roundbook']"));

        new Actions(driver).moveToElement(lMail).perform();


        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement age_purpose = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'popover ng-scope ng-isolate-scope top fade in')]/div/div[@class='popover-inner']"));
        act.moveToElement(age_purpose).perform();
        String tooltiptextreal = age_purpose.getAttribute("innerHTML");[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: attached image for the popup

Comment: Instead of innerHTML USE content.Hope you will get the desire result.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply check if the element present with this xpath.

```
 //div[.='ACE'][content='Advanced .... 1.24.1']
```

Make sure you enter all the tooltip text as content attribute value.

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[.='ACE'][content='toolTipTextGoesHere']")).size()>0){
//pass
}else{
//failed
}
```